# Bootstrap datepicker display issue in Vue project

Tags: html, vue.js, web, bootstrap-4, buefy

I am trying to use b-datepicker to select a date, but I came across an issue. The dates are not displayed properly as you can see in the attached image.

My code

```
    <b-form-group
      class="my-3"
    >
      <b-input-group>
        <b-form-input
          id="example-input"
          v-model="answer"
          type="text"
          placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
          autocomplete="off"
        ></b-form-input>
        <b-input-group-append>
          <b-form-datepicker
            v-model="answer"
            button-only
            right
            lazy
          ></b-form-datepicker>
        </b-input-group-append>
      </b-input-group>
    </b-form-group>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So the solution was to include calendar-width prop in the b-datepicker component